# lxml won't install under pypy using easy_install

Tags: lxml, pypy

When doing:

```
$ sudo pypy -m easy_install lxml
```

The response is:

```
Searching for lxml

[...snip...]

ERROR: /bin/sh: 1: xslt-config: not found

** make sure the development packages of libxml2 and libxslt are installed **

Using build configuration of libxslt 
/usr/lib/pypy/lib-python/2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'bugtrack_url'
  warnings.warn(msg)
warning: no files found matching '*.txt' under directory 'src/lxml/tests'
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:8:22: fatal error: pyconfig.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1
```

At the same time, `sudo pip install lxml` works fine.

What's going on?

Thanks.

Comment: Does your `pip` use `pypy` or CPython?

Comment: `pip` uses CPython for sure.

Comment: This is along the lines of "Have you checked if it's plugged in?", but have you installed the development packages of libxml2 and libxslt? If you're on Debian or Ubuntu, `sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev libxslt-dev` should do the trick. That's probably not the problem -- it's probably related to CPython vs PyPy -- but it's always good to eliminate easy possibilities before delving too deep into the hard cases.

Comment: That is not the problem, @rmunn -- thanks for your input!

Comment: Since it can't find `pyconfig.h`, are you sure you also have `pypy-dev` or the equivalent? And/or can you find `pyconfig.h` anywhere?

Comment: This works for me: `pip install lxml` when run in a virtualenv made with PyPy 2.0.2.

Answer (score 7):

`sudo apt-get install python-dev` fixed it for me on ubuntu 13.04

Comment: Also for Ubuntu 14.04 :)

Comment: It does fix for python but not for pypy. Also tried `sudo apt-get install pypy-dev`

Answer (score 4):

`$yum install python-lxml` or `apt-get install python-lxml`
this solved mine.

Comment: Looks like they're using pypy so you can't use python-lxml as that is likely built against CPython.

Comment: yum install gave me:  No package python-lxml available.
Error: Nothing to do

Answer (score 2):

I've stumbled with this trouble a couple of times.

**Short answer**

```
Python2: $ python2.7 setup.py clean build --with-cython install
Python3: $ pip-3.3 install lxml
```

**Long answer**

The hypothesis is that `pip install lxml` should work in every environment, regardless if you are using Python2 or Python3.

There's also `Cython` to be considered: You will certainly enjoy `lxml` compiled with `Cython` due to relevant performance gains.

For reasons unknown to me, the compilation on Python2 does not find Cython.
To be more precise and absolutely explicit about this matter, both commands below DO NOT employ Cython:

```
# DO NOT use these commands. I repeat: DO NOT use these commands.
$ pip-2.7 install lxml
$ easy_install-2.7 install lxml
```

So, when using Python2 you have only one alternative, as far as I know, which is: compile from sources, Luke!

```
# install build environment and dependencies
$ kernel_release=$( uname -r )
$ sudo apt-get install linux-headers-${kernel_release} build-essential -y
$ sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev -y

# Download from github and compile from sources
$ git clone --branch lxml-3.2.4 https://github.com/lxml/lxml
$ python2.7 setup.py clean build --with-cython install
```

Answer (score 2):

I've handled this problem by installed Ubuntu package `pypy-dev`.

Comment: This is what worked for me with a similar issue with Numpy for pypy.